# Error in composite key in Hibernate org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.Set,

Tags: java, hibernate, composite-key

Friends I have stuck in a Problem in Hibernate composite key.
**Error : org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.Set, at table: IDP_UserManagerMapping, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(idps)]**.I have Tried wit @transient and other things but not effective Please Help.

```
public class IDPUserManagerMapping implements Serializable {
    private Long id;
    private Users user;
    private Users manager;
    private Users assessor;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name="user_id" ,referencedColumnName = "user_id"),
        @JoinColumn(name="manager_id" ,referencedColumnName = "manager_id")
        ,@JoinColumn(name="assessor_id" ,referencedColumnName = "assessor_id")
    })
    @Cascade(CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<IDPMaster> idps = null;

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(sequenceName="idp_usermanagermapping_id_seq",name="idp_usermanagermapping_id_seq_gen")
    @GeneratedValue(generator="idp_usermanagermapping_id_seq_gen")
    @Column(name="id",nullable=false,unique=true,updatable=false)
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Set<IDPMaster> getIdps() {
        return idps;
    }
    public void setIdps(Set<IDPMaster> idps) {
        this.idps = idps;
    }
        @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="user_id",nullable=false)
    public Users getUser() {
        return user;
    }
    public void setUser(Users user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="manager_id",nullable=false)
    public Users getManager() {
        return manager;
    }
    public void setManager(Users manager) {
        this.manager = manager;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="assessor_id")
    public Users getAssessor() {
        return assessor;
    }
    public void setAssessor(Users assessor) {
        this.assessor = assessor;
    }
    }
```

Second Entity

```
public class IDPMaster implements Serializable {
    private Long id;
    private Users managerUser;
    private Users assessorUser;
    private Users idpUsers;
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name="idp_master_id_seq_gen",sequenceName="idp_master_id_seq")
    @GeneratedValue(generator="idp_master_id_seq_gen")
    @Column(name="id",nullable=false,unique=true)
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="user_id",nullable=false)
    public Users getIdpUsers() {
        return idpUsers;
    }
    public void setIdpUsers(Users idpUsers) {
        this.idpUsers = idpUsers;
    }
    @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="manager_id")
    public Users getManagerUser() {
        return managerUser;
    }
    public void setManagerUser(Users managerUser) {
        this.managerUser = managerUser;
    }

    @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="assessor_id")
    public Users getAssessorUser() {
        return assessorUser;
    }
    public void setAssessorUser(Users assessorUser) {
        this.assessorUser = assessorUser;
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move the annotations

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name="user_id" ,referencedColumnName = "user_id"),
        @JoinColumn(name="manager_id" ,referencedColumnName = "manager_id")
        ,@JoinColumn(name="assessor_id" ,referencedColumnName = "assessor_id")
    })
    @Cascade(CascadeType.ALL)
```

from `private Set<IDPMaster> idps = null;`  to `public Set<IDPMaster> getIdps()` getter

Hibernate analyzes annotations by ID column and if you use annotations on getter there you should use getter annotations everywhere.

Comment: But these are Transient members so I kept it in the field.If I do the same then I must mark it `@Transient` annotation.So then will it Work here?